# Invoking Spring based application from a shell script outside the container

Tags: java, spring, shell, applicationcontext

I have a Spring based application using Hibernate deployed in Tomcat. This works perfectly fine when executed within the container or invoking a servlet residing in Tomcat. It reads all the configuration files such as `applicationContext.xml` and other hibernate files. But I have to execute a Java main method from a shell script outside the Tomcat environment.
So, I created a main method within the WAR file which invokes the respective methods.
But I get that `applicationContext` is null when it is invoked via a script.

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
```

The shell script as as below

```
WAR_PATH="/usr/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/AdminTool/WEB-INF"
CLASSPATH=$WAR_PATH/classes
java -classpath $CLASSPATH:$WAR_PATH/lib/*: com.mycompany.controller.BatchController "$1"
```

How can I achieve to have the Spring context working invoked through the script?

Many Thanks

Comment: You'll have to recreate it. new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext(locations).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to tell your application how to initialize the `beanfactory` using ApplicationContext. Depending on what version of Spring you are using. In case you are using version 2 refer to [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html)

---

Instantiating a spring container in Spring 3 [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation)

```
ApplicationContext context =
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the config files are loaded and the whole WAR file is working fine when executed within the Tomcat comtainter context. Its only when I run a main method from an external shell script is causing the problem that the appContext is null.I have the below entries in web.xml 
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: How does your main method know where is the context file? I suppose you would have to explicitly instantiate the `beanfactory` in the main method. `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListene` works for that web app only. Right?

Comment: Main method is within the war file deployed in tomcat. The beans and daos are properly loaded when i start the tomcat. So, I the container is able to locate and load the configs. Its only when the main method is invoked externally from a script that it fails. I have created a simple servlet which internally invokes the main method and when accessed via browser, it works too. Its only when invoked via script that it fails. Could it be a classpath issue in the script?

Comment: @user1860832 When you're running a class from the command line there's no such thing as a web application context-it's just a class; it doesn't matter that it's part of a web app when you're not running it as a web app. Your entry point needs to set up the application context-something that happens in the web app during start up.

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint. Its all working now. I learnt something absolutely new today.

String path[] = {"applicationContext.xml"};


ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();


if(null==appCtx){
 appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path);
}

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a class called Main with a main method. Mark the class with:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.your_base_package"})
@Component
```

In the main method, start by:

```
 ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Controller.class);
    ctx.getBean(Controller.class).invokeTransformationService(pipelineId);
```

The @Configuration annotation will process all annotations. The @ComponentScan is needed to tell Spring container the base package where components will be searched. The @Component makes this class a component so that it is retrievable from ApplicationContext.
Spring container will use these annotations to look for all @Components, create a singleton(by default singleton) and register it with ApplicationContext.